# Rails - Get data from database only on click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have a database named cars with columns such as make, model, year, horsepower, torque, etc.
In my view is a list of the cars in the db by make and model and pic.

How do I go about adding a clickable element such as a link or button that pulls and displays some of the other attributes such as horsepower from the database?

If anyone is familiar with Reddit Enhancement Suite. I'm looking for a solution that's similar to its "expandos" feature.

I've searched around quite a bit for this but I think the answer is simpler than what I'm finding in my searches.

edit: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Just put the extra stuff in a hidden element and show it on click via js...

Comment: Doesn't that mean pre-loading the stuff and just hiding it? Doesn't this waste resources or is what I'm doing so basic that it doesn't matter? 
Sorry should've stated that I'm a rails noob.

Comment: I would imagine that the resources from additional HTTP requests would outweigh those of the few extra attributes. This effect will be magnified if you use caching in your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an high level overview of what needs to be done.

1. On Rails side, create appropriate controller actions and routes for returning json objects for make, model, year, horsepower, torque, etc on request.
2. On client side, write javascript to make ajax call to the server, when a button is clicked. Look in to `on` method in jquery and apply `click` event to it and look up `ajax` method on how to make ajax call to the server.
3. Once you get the json objects from the server, style the dom element for the data and display it on the page.

Answer (score 2):

I second Brad's suggestion. You are over-optimising on something that is unlikely to be a bottleneck for you. If this extra data is just a few extra columns in the db, it's much better just to pre-load and hide it (especially if you can then cache the page-fragments). The http-turnaround is likely to be *much* higher (and result in double server hits) than the small amount of extra db-traffic for a little extra data.

Feel free to profile your app to actually check that this is the case... :)